# Unable to send body parameter in Dart/ Flutter multipart request

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I m trying to upload image using Multipart request using Dart/ Flutter.
but parameter not getting on serverside.

```
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    request.fields['access_token'] = token;
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'image', path.readAsBytesSync(),
          contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpeg')));
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = "multipart/form-data";
    request.headers['access_token'] = token;

    var response = await request.send();
```

Comment: What's not reaching the server.

Comment: access_token i.e. Formdata fields

Comment: Did you find any solution? The payload is empty for me too.

Comment: I used Dio flutter lib

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're sending an empty payload. From the code snippet you've provided, it's possible that `path.readAsBytesSync()` wasn't able to return the File immediately. You can add an `await` keyword on your function to wait for the return value before proceeding to send the Request.